# Simple NodeJS command line with async code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, command-line-interface

I want to create a simple NodeJS command line application to call an API (get AWS CloudFormation export variables) and process it (find the API URL) returning a URL.

I did

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation({
    region: 'ap-southeast-1'
})

cloudformation.listExports({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    const variable = data.Exports.find(e => e.Name === `skynet-server-ApiEndpoint`)
    if (!variable) throw new Error('ApiEndpoint variable not found')
    console.log(variable.Value)
})
```

Which works just fine, but I wonder if it will always work? Like what if the `listExports` take longer? Will the application terminate too early?

Comment: It depends on the aws sdk package, but if an error occurss during listExports, the `err` argument won't be null and it will be thrown and you would see the output in the console.

Comment: `listExports` is async function, the application will not be terminated until a response is received.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS does not limit the time it takes to call your callback.
When you use 3rd party API's they may have a limit. You can check the documentation or the source code of the specific 3rd party API's you need.

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js